# Python - Open CV Error on webcam video capture

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm new to python and opencv. 
I have tried capturing video using cv2.VideoCapture(0), as I have my default video camera as my laptop camera. coded using pycharm and tried all the basic troubleshooting to fix the error. below is my code.
but i tried for cv2.imread('a.jpg') it's working and able to see the pic

````
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```


getting error like this

exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/user2/PycharmProjects/FaceDetect/faceDetect.py", line 6, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
````

Comment: check `ret`....

Comment: Hi @Miki, I have tried the answer you shared on my question but still it's having the same error.

Comment: I have added in `While Loop` as `While cap.isOpned()` and tried but same error.

Comment: Check "ret".....

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for helping me, finally i have found something better `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` tried this and it's working fine. I'm able to open webcam [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/205485/webcam-works-inconsistently/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something went wrong about the environment.

This code works on my laptop.

Please check the value of ret.

Make sure ret == 1.